# AzureRM template Microsoft.Scheduler/jobCollections/jobs request uri with arguments fails

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-scheduler, azure-rm-template

I'm facing a problem when I deploy a template to build a scheduler job with an URI in which I want to pass two arguments.

I want to set as the uri something like "/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyJob/run?arguments=arg1%20arg2"

This works well when typing this through the Azure portal and the job starts without errors, but using an Azure template I see that in the uri the '?' character has been encoded to '%3F', what makes the job to fail because, the route does not exist.

I can't understand why is doing this since, no other character (like '/') is being encoded when deploying the template (at least I can't see it through the Azure portal).

Is this maybe a bug, or is it something I'm maybe doing wrong?

Greetings.

Comment: try casting it to string?

Comment: You already pass a string within the template. However, I tried to use uriComponentToString in the json (just for fun???) and of course, the result is the same.